# Idiom request for describing a situation in which someone give advantages to their enemy or opponent

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

I'm looking for an idiom or proverb that can be used for describing a situation in which someone's actions or behaviors are in favor of their opponents or enemies; in other words it seems that they are serving their enemies' or opponents' interests *(usually unintentionally*).

There is an Iranian proverb that says :

> **"To provide water for (turning) the enemy's mill"**

This proverb mostly is used among politicians when they are accusing each other of giving advantages to the country's enemies, their opponents or the opposite parties.

For example:

It is supposed that a public election be held for choosing the members of the parliament on 26 February in Iran. Regarding the importance of this election,  the supreme leader of the country has asked the politicians  to stop using discouraging words or showing reactions that would lead people not to participate in the election. Because if the election is not recieved well by the people, it would be considered as a sign of their dissatisfaction from the current leaders and thus "*would provide water for the country's enemies' mill".*

What do English speakers use in this situation that can convey the same meaning?

I have come across this title [" loading the gun of the enemy"](http://www.mydailydose.org/index.cfm?View=2541) in a website, but couldn't find it as a set phrase in available dictionaries.

[image]

Comment: In Tamil, there's a colloquial saying, which roughly translates into English as - "Don't put the devil in your undergarments". In you case, the devil here refers to public anger caused by any malicious actions by the politicians(hate speech, racial slurs) that would put the party in a precarious position before the election phase (metaphorically refers to the burning sensation in the underpants :D)

Comment: One possible but not great term would be "handicapping" yourself in a competition or contest.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could say they would be ***playing into the hands*** of the enemy.

> **play into somebody's hands**
>
> to do something that gives someone else an advantage over you, although this was not your intention
>
> *If we allow terrorists to disrupt our lives to that extent we're just playing into their hands.*

<sub>Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.. (2006). Retrieved February 24 2016 from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+into+hands</sub>

According to [this source,](http://rollsoffthetongue.tumblr.com/post/47424407683/play-into-someones-hand-origin-this-expression) the expression originated from playing cards, specifically the game *bridge*. The source gives nice outline of its emergence:

> A part of the game’s strategy is to force your opponent to play certain cards. If you manage to do so, then she or he is *playing into your hand*, giving you an advantage. The expression is often pluralized into *playing into someone’s hands*. This slight modification has resulted in obscuring the origin of the meaning, making people think of a body part, when actually in card games your hand, refers to the cards you are holding. This meaning goes all the way back to the 16th century as well.

This idiom is very common in the UK, and is also often said with emphasis and pluralised as mentioned above:

> *played it **right** into my hands*

Searching for the above on Google Books will give you plenty of examples of the use of this phrase in print.

https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22played+right+into+my+hands%22

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,@Charon. Can  I say "Those discouraging words would finally play into the enemy's hand"?

Comment: I'm not sure of your context but I don't think it's idiomatic to use `finally` there, I'd simply say *saying those discouraging words would be playing into the enemy's hands*

Comment: @Soudabeh No problem :) please notice however that I've made a little edit to my comment.

Comment: @Soudabeh Might be useful to note that this phrase [comes from playing cards](http://rollsoffthetongue.tumblr.com/post/47424407683/play-into-someones-hand-origin-this-expression).

Comment: What @DCShannon said. I'm in a nit-picky mood, so I'm downvoting because if the *etymology* of a figurative usage isn't blindingly obvious, it ***must*** be explained in the actual text as presented here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's pretty harsh... It's certainly *very welcome* when people provide non-obivous etymology, but is there any rule written anywhere saying it's *essential*? I'm sure I'm not the only native speaker who has used this phrase without knowing that (I'd always wrongly assumed it came from sports like rugby)

Comment: @DCShannon - thanks, I've included your source in my answer. It would be nice to have some evidence or corroboration for the origin that it asserts, though.

Comment: @user568458: There's certainly no rule saying I *shouldn't* downvote for reasons like that. And it's obviously had the desired effect - Charon has duly incorporated DCShannon's point into the answer, and I've reversed my downvote. *And* if in future someone posts a question asking about the meaning/origin of *to play into someone's hands*, I'd now be able to closevote it as a duplicate. Wins all round! :)

Comment: @Charon Yeah, I didn't look super hard for a reference. I was already aware it came from cards.

Comment: @DCShannon: I'd never thought about the etymology / "literal" meaning until I saw your comment (which at the time I accepted at face value). But actually, on further consideration, I'm not particularly convinced. I'm pretty sure even in C16 it would have been possible to say *He's playing into **my hands*** - which is nonsense in relation to *Bridge*, and more than a bit odd for any other card game context I can imagine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know what you mean by C16, and I'm confused by everything after it. The one source I found said that the pluralization of hand came later on. Playing into someone's *hand* is perfectly sensible in every card game I can think of that involves any degree of strategy (not War).

Comment: @DCShannon: Your link above starts with *This expression has its origin in card playing, most likely Bridge, or Whist. Those games go back to the 16th century* (C16). But OED doesn't explicitly mention that origin, and I note they say *In early use **play** is often **transitive** with the desired **advantage or result as the object***, which I think steers us *away* from that "theory". I don't say I reject it out of hand, but I'm not fully convinced as yet.

Comment: And there is also ```to give someone the upper hand```

Comment: worth mentioning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugzwang

Answer (score 21):

**give [sb] a stick to beat you with**.

Example: *If things go badly, you may be giving your opponents a stick to beat you with*.

Comment: That's old school right there.

Comment: +1 I think this fits the intended usage rather well (creating an opportunity for others to criticise), but you should probably add a link to an example definition etc. There's also "[Making a rod for your own back](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-a-rod-for-your-own-back)", but I think your one is better, I believe the "rod" one is British English only and the meaning is less obvious (it's less obvious that the rod is for beating/whipping your back with).

Comment: What's `[sb]` mean?

Comment: @Carcigenicate - [sb] stands for the optional word "somebody" .

Answer (score 19):

It may not be so common in AmE, but in BrE you can certainly...

> *(score) [an **own goal**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/an+own+goal)*
>    *something that someone does to try to get an advantage, but which makes a situation worse for them*
>   Usage notes: In sport, an own goal is when someone **scores a point for the opposite team** by mistake.

Comment: We'd be familiar with that in the US, although some might think of hockey rather than soccer.

Comment: @DCShannon Even moreso here in Canada.

Answer (score 13):

Consider,

***give someone all the ammunition they need***; [***give someone ammunition to use against someone/oneself***](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/tendre-une-perche.549076/)

> ammunition: A means of attacking or defending an argument, thesis, or point of view. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ammunition)
>
> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22gave+them+ammunition+to+use+against%22&biw=476&bih=313&prmd=nsiv&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5_rXBmpHLAhUH2xoKHeDBBnEQ_AUICygG&dpr=2)

***be (all) grist for someone's mill***

> grist for someone's mill: Something that can be used to advantage. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grist)
>
> *In retirement, Gehlen bitterly complained, “For week after week the [Felfe] affair continued to hold the newspaper headlines: his character, his Nazi past, and his subsequent treachery were all grist for their mill, resulting in exaggerated reports.* [A Nazi Past](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=677&bih=444&tbm=bks&q=%22all+grist+for+their+mill%22&oq=%22all+grist+for+their+mill%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...4778.18324.0.18655.46.36.0.0.0.0.401.6224.0j14j13j2j1.30.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..19.6.1094.lJd6uV-IltY)

***fuel someone's arguments***

> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22fueled+their+arguments%22&biw=322&bih=212&prmd=vin&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh8rGhl5LLAhXCORoKHbPxA24Q_AUICygG)

***make it easy for someone***

***make oneself an easy target***

[WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/tendre%20la%20perche%20%C3%A0%20qqn)

***make oneself a sitting duck***

> sitting duck: an easy target [FOD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sitting+duck)

***give someone a [through ball](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-french/through-ball)***

> through ball: (*Soccer*) A forward pass which goes through the opposing team’s defense.

Comment: +1, to speak to the example: "saying those discouraging words would be giving them all the ammunition they need"

Answer (score 9):

If you made it unexpectedly easy for an opponent to win, you "handed them victory on a silver platter."

In which case, their victory came "gift-wrapped."

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the most famous expression to this effect in recent U.S. history is the [remark by Richard Nixon](https://books.google.com/books?id=9NZ8BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=%22twisted+it+with+relish%22&source=bl&ots=eRjJZ9C38L&sig=KGo-iHwlmbfP47LXNXDTHtip-54&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUqs_Yv5HLAhUN2GMKHXYEDUwQ6AEIVzAN#v=onepage&q=%22twisted%20it%20with%20relish%22&f=false) to David Frost in an interview conducted in 1977, speaking of his political enemies:

> I gave them a sword, and they stuck it in and they twisted it with relish.

The resulting expression—"to give [one's enemies] a sword"—is not especially widely used in the United States, but the original quotation is widely remembered, and sometimes used in the same figurative way. Thus, Kate Michelman, [*Protecting the Right to Choose*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oQeaDDhXzgIC&pg=PT122&dq=%22Clinton+but+to+paraphrase+Richard+Nixon%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio_4PvxJHLAhUO2mMKHTzxDKsQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Clinton%20but%20to%20paraphrase%20Richard%20Nixon%22&f=false) (2007) includes this passage:

> He [Bill Clinton] continued to veto anti-choice measures, including the abortion ban, despite the [Lewinsky] scandal. And nothing about the situation justified impeachment, a grave step vastly out of proportion to the offense, however personally inexcusable it was. The right wing was dedicated to the personal destruction of President Clinton, but to paraphrase Richard Nixon, "He gave them a sword."

Answer (score 4):

Relevant, but perhaps not completely on the mark:

[To shoot oneself in the foot](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+in+the+foot)

*"To do or say something that inadvertently undermines one's interests."*

It misses out on notion of directly helping an enemy, but that can be taken care of by constructing the sentence well.

Comment: This one has much in common with *cut off one's nose (to spite one's face)*, in that it's not a very successful tactic. But it doesn't really evoke allusions to "helping the enemy".

Comment: Yeah, completely agree, it sort of has the same idea - undermining your own interests certainly might help your enemy -  but the "helping" is passive/incidental rather than active and direct which the original saying implies

Comment: Perhaps someone will post **To give up** :)

Comment: also: to snatch defeat from the jaws of victory

Answer (score 2):

Your example infers that certain action would negatively affect voter turnout which would affect many people negatively but if you could speak in a collective sense, the people opting not to vote would be ***"cutting off their nose to spite their face"***.

The definition for this expression on [UsingEnglish.com](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/cut+off+your+nose+to+spite+your+face.html) is:

> " If you cut off your nose to spite your face, you do something rash or silly that ends up making things worse for you, often because you are angry or upset."

Comment: I'm not sure this is really central to the concept of "promoting one's enemy's cause", but it certainly raises the interesting issue of whether *multiple* people should be accused of [*cutting off their **nose***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cutting+off+their+nose+to%22) to spite their ***face(s)*** (About 833 results in Google Books) or [*cutting off their **noses**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cutting+off+their+noses+to%22) to spite their face(s?!)*  (About 1,230 results). How many people? How many noses? I think we should be told!

Answer (score 1):

To "**throw the game**" is a similar idiom, though perhaps not conveying the exact meaning you want of being unintentional. It is a common phrase in sporting events and means intentionally making moves or plays to give your opponent an advantage, or to diminish your own, usually resulting in a win for your opponent.

Answer (score 1):

Another phrase is ""**to carry water for someone**" or "**to carry their water**".

From [Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carry_someone%27s_water):

> "To do someone's bidding; to serve someone's interests."